# Velocity level constraints on the inverse kinematic trajectory

Tags: drake

I have a question about `inverseKinTraj` class.
It seems to return `qsol` as well as `qdotsol` and `qddotsol` and I would like to add velocity constraint on the time step.
For example, I would like to add `A(q(t))*qdot(t) = Constant` and `(q(t+1)-q(t))/dt=qdot(t+1)`. Is there any way I could impose velocity level constraints on the inverse kinematic trajectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inverseKinTraj` doesn't offer the API for constraint `A(q(t)) * qdot(t) = constant`. 
Moreover, `inverseKinTraj` assumes that the trajectory is a piecewise cubic spline (namely it has continuous joint velocity/acceleration), so we cannot do the backward Euler integration `(q(t+1) - q(t)) / dt = qdot(t+1)`, which doesn't give a continuous joint velocity/acceleration.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think for the aforementioned types of constraint, I should use ```SingleTimeLinearPostureConstraint``` and ```inverseKin``` with previous solution ```q_prev``` instead.
For example, ```A(q_prev)*q_sol = constant * dt + A(q_prev)*q_qprev```

Comment: Yes, if `A(q(t))` could be a fixed matrix, then you can do `A(q_prev)*q_sol = constant * dt + A(q_prev)*q_qprev`.